# Monodevelop bug by clicking on the console in Unity3d

Tags: monodevelop, unity-game-engine

Unity opens two tabs in Monodevelop with the same file. How to get rid of this problem?
Monodevelop 3.0.5
Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABSbI8sMHLU

Answer (score -2):

Maybe Visual studio is a good choice for replace of Mono.by using visual you can even check the metadata,and definitely it only open one tab in same project.